# PostGIS performance using ST_Subdivide

Tags: postgis, postgresql

What is the max or optimal number of vertices for a geometry to improve performance and load time, using ST_Subdivide? What would be the max or optimal shape length? I am trying to find the best balance between the number of geometries vs the size of each geometry or shape length.

Comment: A proper answer for this question could fill several pages. Some **rules of thumb**: for *Point*-in-*Polygon* and *Line*-intersection checks, as well as proximity searches (i.e. `ST_DWithin`) and specific overlay checks on arbitrary geometry types (e.g. `ST_Intersects` in an `EXISTS` condition - not necessarily in a `JOIN`, though) you *generally* cannot have enough subdivisions; for more restrictive and encompassing predicates on arbitrary types (e.g. `ST_Contains`) subdivision is rather useless. Anything in between is case specific...

Comment: Note that the benefit of subdividing geometries stems from the interplay of (subsequently increased) index efficiency and reduced per-geometry vertex count - you need both for this to make sense.

Comment: Let's note that with the default storage method (`main`), more than 128 vertices will see the geometry being compressed and more than 512 will see the geometry moved to toast.

Comment: Performance is a broad term. Performance in a map canvas load? Or performance amongst other geometry creating operations. Or performance when doing data searches (which is similar to a map load but doesn't need to be mindful of aesthetics).  One reason not to subdivide is if the linework needs to be displayed in a cartographic form without randon non-meaningful boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

Hello @marieneighe   If I were in your shoes, my question is only;
***To Subdivide or Not To Subdivide***

As a matter of routine I refer to the below when a new dataset comes in

#### Do a test on the size of the largest feature

```sql
SELECT concat(ROUND(MAX(ST_Area(Box2D(geom)))::NUMERIC / ST_Area(ST_Extent(geom))::NUMERIC*100,0),' %') AS max
FROM a.big_veg_map
;
```

#### Test for complexity

```sql
/* complexity of processing   low numbers are good
  max size < 7.5%
  max pts < 1,000,000
  max rings < 100
  max inte rings < 20
  sqd_geom_metric <57%    */

SELECT
CONCAT(ROUND(MAX(ST_Area(Box2D(geom)))::NUMERIC / ST_Area(ST_Extent(geom))::NUMERIC*100,0),' %') AS max_size,
ROUND(MAX(ST_NPoints(geom))::NUMERIC,0) AS max_pts,
ROUND(MAX(ST_NRings(geom))::NUMERIC,0) AS max_rings,
MAX(ST_NumInteriorRings(ST_GeometryN(geom, 1))) AS max_int_rings,
CONCAT(ROUND((1-(AVG((ST_Area(geom) / ST_Area(Box2D(geom)))))::NUMERIC)*100,0),' %')  AS sqd_geom_metric
FROM a.big_veg_map
;
```

Then cut them up - https://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2019/11/subdivide.html

Comment: Thank you very much!